# Adminhtml - How to create New Admin Form

Tags: magento-1.9, php, mysql

I'm using Magento 1.9.0.1 and right now i'm developing a new magento extension.

So far i've created new adminhtml page with grid table that is fetching data from custom MySQL table:

Here is the page:

[image]

This page is fetching data from custom MySQL table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification` here is the structure of it:

[image]

Let me show you my extension files:

I have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource</resourceModel>
        </smsnotification>
        <vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
        <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <smsnotification>
            <table>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</table>
            </smsnotification>
        </entities>
        </vivasindustries_smsnotification_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <smsnotification_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                 <use>core_setup</use>
             </connection>
        </smsnotification_setup>
        <smsnotification_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_read>
        <smsnotification_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </smsnotification_write>
    </resources>    
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smsnotification>
                    <class>smsnotification/observer</class>
                    <method>orderSaved</method>
                </vivasindustries_smsnotification>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
    <helpers>
        <smsnotification>
            <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Helper</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
        <smsnotification>
             <class>VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block</class>
        </smsnotification>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <adminhtml>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <vivas>
                                        <title>Vivas - All</title>
                                    </vivas>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
    </adminhtml>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <VivasIndustries_SmsNotification before="Mage_Adminhtml">VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml</VivasIndustries_SmsNotification>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_blockGroup = 'smsnotification';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_sms_status';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Send SMS on Order Status Changes');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Create new SMS Rule');
        parent::__construct();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->setChild( 'grid',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock( $this->_blockGroup.'/' . $this->_controller . '_grid',
                $this->_controller . '.grid')->setSaveParametersInSession(true) );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }



}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Grid.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('smsnotification_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }


    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('smsnotification/smsnotification_collection');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }


    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
          $this->addColumn('id', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('ID'),
              'align'     =>'right',
              'width'     => '50px',
              'index'     => 'id',
          ));

          $this->addColumn('Receiver', array(
              'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Receiver'),
              'align'     =>'left',
              'index'     => 'Receiver',
          ));

        $this->addColumn('Phone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Phone'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Phone',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Date', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('smsnotification')->__('Date'),
            'align'     =>'left',
            'index'     => 'Date',

        ));


        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
    }
}
```

Here is what i have in: /app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/controllers/Adminhtml/SmsorderstatusesController.php:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Adminhtml_SmsorderstatusesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__('SMS Center'))->_title($this->__('SMS Center'));
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status'));
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status_grid')->toHtml()
        );
    }

   public function newAction()
    {  
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('vivassms');
        $this->renderLayout();
    }  

    public function editAction()
    {  
        $this->_initAction();

        // Get id if available
        $id  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $model = Mage::getModel('smsnotification/smsnotification');


        $this->_initAction()
            ->_addBreadcrumb($id ? $this->__('Edit Baz') : $this->__('New Baz'), $id ? $this->__('Edit Baz') : $this->__('New Baz'))
            ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('smsnotification/adminhtml_sms_status_edit')->setData('action', $this->getUrl('*/*/save')))
            ->renderLayout();
    }

    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            // Make the active menu match the menu config nodes (without 'children' inbetween)
            ->_setActiveMenu('vivassms')
            ->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Baz'))
            ->_addBreadcrumb($this->__('Sales'), $this->__('Sales'))
            ->_addBreadcrumb($this->__('Baz'), $this->__('Baz'));

        return $this;
    }


    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/foo_bar_baz');
    }
}
```

Right now when i click on `Create new SMS Rule` button i get blank page like this:

[image]

What i want to achieve is:

1. I want to display in the blank page shown above 3 input fields (Receiver, Phone, Date) in which i can insert data.
2. I want to have `Save` button and i hit it. The data entered in the 3 fields i want to be saved in the MySQL table `VivasIndustries_SmsNotification`.

Why i receive a blank page when i click on `Create new SMS Rule` and how can i make what i want in the two points above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need a form and a form container. It's similar to what you already did with the grid.

You must create these files:

/app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Edit.php

```
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit 
     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
```

/app/code/community/VivasIndustries/SmsNotification/Block/Adminhtml/Sms/Status/Edit/Form.php

```
class VivasIndustries_SmsNotification_Block_Adminhtml_Sms_Status_Edit_Form 
     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
```

Checkout the **Form Container Block** section in [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/03/13/tutorial-create-admin-manageable-magento-entity-brands/) (It's a really good one). You should render these blocks in the appropiate action in the controller, and add an extra action to handle the form submission. This second action receives the data via `POST`, passes it to the model and saves it to the database.

Comment: Can you please give me the content for these files. I really don't know what to paste in there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code is in the article I linked ;) You will have to do some modifications for it to work, because it is based on a different model used for that example, but it's pretty clear and it should be a good excercise. Give it a try, and if you still can't manage it, I'll see if I can edit the answer later tonight (I'm at work right now). Do try and read the article. It's the one that got me started with magento extensions and I learned a lot from it! It's incredibly detailed.

Comment: This guide is giving me so many errors like it is described in the comments of the guide. I've tried everything what they say in the comments but i still have the errors. So i'll be very thankful to you if you help me out with full example. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also this guide is missing the `newAction` method so it feels incomplete.. :P

Comment: It is not missing the `newAction`, it just does both in the `editAction`. It uses the same form to create and to edit. I'll try to provide a full example tonight though. You'll just have to wait a little.

Comment: So far i've made it but i still have some problems, please check this thing out: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55808/adminhtml-blank-edit-form-not-showing-data-in-the-edit-input-fields